# Specify column width while exporting

Tags: export, list-manipulation, files-and-directories

I am trying to export a set of data into a file but I can not force mathematica to keep a certain width for each column. For example, when I export a table:

```
table={{10,2},{3,40}};
Export["file.dat",table, "Table", "FieldSeparators"->" ", Alignment->Right]
```

The result is:

```
10  2
 2 40
```

Mathematica automatically determines column width such that the number with largest number of digits fits in. How can I export data with arbitrary space in each column to get:

```
 10    2
  2   40
```

such that `"FieldSeparators"->" "` is still the same but first column has space for three digits and the second one has space for 4 digits?

Comment: Use tab as field separators. Then it is machine readable as you have only one separator and most [nice text editors](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) align your columns.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to do the padding manually:

```
padToWidth[width_, n_] := StringJoin@PadLeft[Characters@ToString[n], width, " "]

newData = MapAt[padToWidth[4, #] &, data, {All, 1}]; (* Apply to first column *)
newData = MapAt[padToWidth[3, #] &, newData, {All, 2}]; (* Apply to second column *)
Export["data.dat", StringJoin[First@#, " ", Last@#] & /@ newData]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
table = {{10, 2}, {3, 40}};

export = (Transpose@IntegerString@table)[[#]] /. 
 a_String :> Table[" ", {# + 2 - StringLength@a}] <> a & /@ {1, 2} // Transpose;

Export["file.dat", export, "Table"]
```

[image]